# how java stores data structures

Tags: java

i havent been able to find any good answers, but in data structures such as arrays, does java store the objects in the array or pointers to said objects,

this is an example of where this would be relevant is i have an object that takes 50 bytes and want to organize it in 2 different ways without having to sort it before each search so i have it in 2 arrays. is that going to take 2*50*n bytes or ((2*2)+50)*n assuming pointers are 2bytes

i understand thats not exact but if n was 2000 it would be close

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there are two main types - primitives and objects. Objects are always stored in heap and your variable is a pointer. For example `int[]`, stores the values, whereas `Integer[]` stores pointers to `Integer` instances which have an `int` field.

Answer (score 2):

Only one copy of each object will exist, and a reference will be stored in each array. Although it is transparent to you, the objects that you are creating aren't actually being stored 'inside' the array, the array is just a mechanism that Java uses to indicate "this series of objects in this order". What the array actually consists of is a series of pointers, which are either 32, or 64 bits (depending on what hardware your program is running on). It doesn't matter what size your object is, the pointer will still be the same.

So if you want to store both of those objects in two different arrays the total amount of memory used will be `n*50+2*2*n`. `n*50` because that's how much memory is needed to store those objects, and `2*2*n` for the two sets of pointers that make up each array.

Comment: Actually, technically, another 2 pointers will need to be added, for the references to the arrays themselves.

Answer (score 2):

All objects in Java are handled by reference -- when you have an array of anything other than a primitive data type the array contains only pointers. It's not possible (as it is in C) to construct an array (or, for that matter, any other type of object) which stores values rather than references.

So to answer your example from above, the Java array takes ((2*2)+50)*n bytes. 2*2*n for your two pointer arrays, and n*50 for your objects.

Answer (score 0):

In Java all objects are pointers. Hence, any array, immaterial of its content objects, is the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Several others have answered the immediate question. I'll just add two minor points:

1. Trivial technicality: I think pointers in Java are generally 4 bytes, though this is not specified in any spec and is thus implementation dependent.
2. Definitely not a trivial technicality: What is stored in the array is not the object itself but a pointer -- in Java terminology called a "handle". So suppose you have two arrays pointing to the same set of object, say "arrayByFoo" and "arrayByBar", and arrayByFoo[42] refers to the same object as arrayByBar[27]. Then you say arrayByFoo[42].setPlugh(3). You have changed the OBJECT, so if you later say arrayByBar[27].getPlugh() , it should return the updated value, 3.

On the other hand, if you say arrayByFoo[42]=new MyObject(), you have now changed the reference, so arrayByFoo[42] is not longer equal to arrayByBar[27]. arrayByBar is still pointing to the old object, while arrayByFoo is now pointing to the new one. (Assuming you don't also update arrayByBar, of course.)